# creating dynamic selectOneRadion using a bean

Tags: java, jsf, javabeans, selectoneradio

I need to build an app of Quiz that contains questions (each question has 2 possible answers) I stored some questions in database. once you select an answer and click "Next", you'll see the next question. 
I have a bean that represent each question, it's called Item, and has the attributes: 
question, ansA, ansB;
and I have a bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Bean {

private List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
private List<Item> helper = new ArrayList<Item>();
private String myValue;
int indexHelp = 0;

public String next() {
    items.clear();
    items.add(helper.get(indexHelp));
    indexHelp++;

    System.out.println("chose: " + myValue);

    return "ok";
}
```

the list helper is stored already with the questions from the database

the jsf file:

```
<h:form>
        <h:dataTable value="#{bean.items}" var="item">
            <h:selectOneRadio value="#{bean.myValue}">
                <h:column>
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{item.question}"      />
                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                    <f:selectItem itemValue="1" itemLabel="#{item.ansA}" />
                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                    <f:selectItem itemValue="2" itemLabel="#{item.ansB}" />
                </h:column>

            </h:selectOneRadio>
        </h:dataTable>
        <h:commandButton value="Next" action="#{bean.next}" />
    </h:form>
```

the problem is that when I run the project, it doesn't show the radio buttons, the question or the answers.
Thank you!!

Comment: Okay, I thought I figured out what you wanted, but your description and your code contradict. You say you want to show only one question, why do you iterate over a list, then?

Answer (score 0):

Here's something that matches your description:

```
public class Item {
     String question;
     String chosen;
     String ansA;
     String ansB;
}

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public AnswerBean implements Serializable {
     private List<Item> alreadyAnswered = new ArrayList<>();
     private Item nextQuestion;

     @PostConstruct
     public void retrieveNextQuestion() {
         // pull "next" question from DB and assign it to nextQuestion
     }

     public void save() {
         alreadyAnswered.add(nextQuestion);
         retrieveNextQuestion();
     }
}
```

And your JSF page goes like this:

```
<h:form>
    <h:outputText value="#{answerBean.nextQuestion.question}" />
    <h:selectOneRadio value="#{answerBean.nextQuestion.chosen}">
        <f:selectItem itemValue="1" itemLabel"#{answerBean.nextQuestion.ansA}" />
        <f:selectItem itemValue="2" itemLabel"#{answerBean.nextQuestion.ansB}" />
    </h:selectOneRadio>
    <h:commandButton action="#{answerBean.save}" value="Next" />
</h:form>
```

You probably want to add a "evaluate" button that you show when there's no question left or something (since you need to *do* something with the `alreadyAnswered` list of questions).

Comment: It works perfectly good! But when I run it and choose an answer and press Next, the next question is marked with the same answer as I chose at the former question. Do you know how do I clear the radio button (after clicking Next..) ?

Comment: @user3168286 The `selectOneRadio` will show the value matching `nextQuestion.chosen`. Just make sure that's `null` after your call to `save()`.